# jsReport How to get data dynamically using AJAX GET Request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, jsreport

I want to use jsreport in order to generate dynamically some reports on my website (asp.net core App) and I have a method in the controller that returns a JSON, and I want to get data from there using jsReport to fill a report.

I will post some test values.
**Controller**

```
public JsonResult testReport()
{
         FileStream fs = new FileStream("path\\json.txt", FileMode.Open);

        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(fs))
        {
            var model = r.ReadToEnd();
            test json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<test>(model);


            return Json(json);
        }   
 }   

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> MyAction([FromServices] INodeServices nodeServices)
    {
        var result = await nodeServices.InvokeAsync<byte[]>
            ("./pdf");
        HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

        string filename = @"report.pdf";
        HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("x-filename", filename);
        HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "x-filename");
        HttpContext.Response.Body.Write(result, 0, result.Length);
        return new ContentResult();
    }
```

**and the actual scripts that run on the page:**

```
module.exports = function (callback) {
    var jsreport = require('jsreport-core')();

    jsreport.init().then(function () {
        return jsreport.render({
            template: {
                content: 'template bla bla bla',
                engine: 'jsrender',
                recipe: 'phantom-pdf'
            },
            data: /* i don`t know how to get data from (/Home/testReport) */
        }).then(function (resp) {
            callback(/* error */ null, resp.content.toJSON().data);
        });
    }).catch(function (e) {
        callback(/* error */ e, null);
    });
};
```

I have checked with hardcoded and values and it works, I have problems when it comes to dynamically getting data.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solde this. The problem was that I tried to run client side script on server, which actually made no sense. So I fixed it by making the get request in the script that I  run on the server. Final result:

```
module.exports = function (callback) {
var request = require("request");
var getResponse = null;

request.get({
    url: '/Home/testReport',
    json: true,
}, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200)
        getResponse = body;
    });

var jsreport = require('jsreport-core')();

jsreport.init().then(function () {
    return jsreport.render({
        template: {
            content: 'template bla  bla bla',
            engine: 'jsrender',
            recipe: 'phantom-pdf'
        },
        data: getResponse
    }).then(function (resp) {
        callback(/* error */ null, resp.content.toJSON().data);
    });
}).catch(function (e) {
    callback(/* error */ e, null);
});
```

};

Comment: Mirel, this code may have tested out OK, but it's very fragile - it's not a reliable solution. `request.get()` is asynchronous, as is `jsreport.init()`. There's no guarantee which will respond first - could be a...b or b...a . You can indeed fire off both async processes in parallel but you need to use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait for *both* to settle before attempting  to render.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the data is just another asynchronous task, therefore include it in your promise chain in such a way that it delivers the data to where it is needed.

Let's assume you are using `fetch()` to get the data ...

```
module.exports = function () {
    var jsreport = require('jsreport-core')();
    return jsreport.init()
    .then(function() {
        return fetch({/* params */})
    })
    .then(function(fetchedData) {
        return jsreport.render({
            template: {
                content: 'template bla bla bla',
                engine: 'jsrender',
                recipe: 'phantom-pdf'
            },
            data: fetchedData
        });
    });
};
```

Note: All mention of `callback` has been removed. By returning a promise from the function, the caller can chain `.then(...).catch(...);` to the function call without the need to pass a callback (at least, not in the same way).

Comment: hi, i was wondering where will go the $.get('Home/testReport',{},function(...)), in order to get the data from URL. sorry if this is a stupid question, but it`s first time with jquery/js

Comment: Where is the javascript supposed to run? The question is confusing in that `module.exports` and `require` imply server-side Node.js, the `ASP.new-core` tag implies ASP, and now your mention of `$.get()` implies client-side javascript. My answer assumes Node.js.

Comment: I get your point, i mismatched where those scripts execute. Thank you1